# How to get Program Files folder path (not Program Files (x86)) from 32bit WOW process?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I need to get the path to the native (rather than the WOW) program files directory from a 32bit WOW process.

When I pass CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES (or CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86) into SHGetSpecialFolderPath it returns the WOW (Program Files (x86)) folder path.

I'd prefer to avoid using an environment variable if possible.

I want to compare some values I read from the registry, if the values point to the path of either the WOW or native version of my app then my code does something, if not it does something else. 
To figure out where the native and WOW versions of my app are expected to be I need to get the paths to "Program Files (x86)" and "Program Files".

Comment: You should NOT rely on where your program "is expected to be". The apps are where the user wants them. Small SSDs are becoming popular, and they'll add extra install locations to many PCs.

Comment: Totally, but in this case it really will be in the program files folder.

Comment: For me, the why is updating an extensions list for Chrome, which might be in AppData, Program Files (x86) or Program Files. (Of course, the name of Program Files could be something else.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I appreciate all the help and, especially, the warnings in this thread. However, I really do need this path and this is how I got it in the end:

(error checking removed for clarity, use at your own risk, etc)

```
WCHAR szNativeProgramFilesFolder[MAX_PATH];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(L"%ProgramW6432%", 
                       szNativeProgramFilesFolder, 
                       ARRAYSIZE(szNativeProgramFilesFolder);
```

Comment: Thank you! Under a special circumstance, I need this exactly.

Answer (score 12):

Let me quote **Raymond Chen**'s [excellent blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/22/9244582.aspx) on the issue:

> On 64-bit Windows, 32-bit programs run
>   in an emulation layer. This emulation
>   layer simulates the x86 architecture,
>   virtualizing the CPU, the file system,
>   the registry, the environment
>   variables, the system information
>   functions, all that stuff. If a 32-bit
>   program tries to look at the system,
>   it will see a 32-bit system. For
>   example, if the program calls the
>   GetSystemInfo function to see what
>   processor is running, it will be told
>   that it's running on a 32-bit
>   processor, with a 32-bit address
>   space, in a world with a 32-bit sky
>   and 32-bit birds in the 32-bit trees.
>
> And that's the point of the emulation:
>   To keep the 32-bit program happy by
>   simulating a 32-bit execution
>   environment.
>
> ...
>
> The question is "What is the way of
>   finding the x64 Program Files
>   directory from a 32-bit application?"
>
> The answer is "**It is better to work
>   with the system than against it.**" If
>   you're a 32-bit program, then you're
>   going to be fighting against the
>   emulator each time you try to interact
>   with the outside world. Instead, just
>   recompile your installer as a 64-bit
>   program. Have the 32-bit installer
>   detect that it's running on a 64-bit
>   system and launch the 64-bit installer
>   instead. The 64-bit installer will not
>   run in the 32-bit emulation layer, so
>   when it tries to copy a file or update
>   a registry key, it will see the real
>   64-bit file system and the real 64-bit
>   registry.

If you still want to do this, I recommend reading the comments on this blogpost as they contain some good hints.

Comment: One totally legitimate use case for getting the 64b ProgFiles from a 32b program is when it's trying to back up your computer but wants to ignore Program Files. Of course you want to ignore the 64b Program Files folder too.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right path - Use the [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584(VS.85).aspx) of FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64

The [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx) function can be used to retrieve the full path of a given KnownFolder.

Comment: Isn't that only available on Vista or later? What happens when codde calls this on pre-Vista Windows?

Comment: I just hit that problem, I need it to work on XP and Server 2003 x64 too.

Comment: SHGetKnownFolderPath with FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 does not work on 32-bit versions of Windows. It is/was documented as working but, unfortunately, it does not actually work. See the Community Content section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bad idea, according to a recent-ish post by the infamous Raymond Chen.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/22/9244582.aspx) for details.  Bottom line, I think it can be done, but it's a lot of hard work and there's almost certainly an easier way.

Microsoft built the WOW emulation layer to make your life easier. Don't waste all their time and effort by fighting it :-).

Perhaps if you told us **why** you need the non-WOW Program Files directory, we could assist further.

Answer (score 1):

I needed it to get the x64 Program Folder from a Logonscript and used:

```
Dim oWshShell : Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sProgramDirPath : sProgramDirPath = 
    oWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramW6432%")

WScript.Echo sProgramDirPath
```

Answer (score -3):

The best and universal way to get path to "Program Files", is to query it from the registry:

64-Bit-Process can query:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir**
*to get "C:\Program Files"*
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir**
*to get "C:\Program Files (x86)"*

32-Bit-Process (Wow64) can query:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir**
*to get "C:\Program Files (x86)"*
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir** with **KEY_WOW64_64KEY** option!
*to get "C:\Program Files"*

Pseudo-code:

```
OpenKey(hKey, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
QueryStringValue(hKey, L"ProgramFilesDir", sValue);
```

Comment: You should use the API functions to fetch the location: SHGetFolderPath or ExpandEnvironmentStrings.

Comment: What if the registry keys change in Windows 9?